# Prevent textbox suggestions on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, devexpress

I need to build an autocomplete textbox and it's working. But on mobile phone before my autocomplete there are the browser suggestions.
So my users keep inserting new data instead of clicking on the one from the database.
Is possible to disable browser suggestions for specific textbox (or per application level)?

Now i'm used Devextreme autocomplete, but also with a classic textbox there's this problem.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `autocomplete="off"` property to the `input` you want to stop browser suggestions on, Also, you can disable all suggestions on all inputs of a form, if you add the same `property` to the `form` itself.

Ex:

```
<form autocomplete="off">... inputs here</form>
```

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

[How to Disable the Browser Autocomplete and Autofill on HTML Form and Input Fields](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-disable-browser-autocomplete-and-autofill-on-html-form-and-input-fields.html#:%7E:text=Add%20autocomplete%3D%22off%22%20onto,input%3E%20element%20of%20the%20form.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to write the specification. I used autocomplete="off" both on form and input, also autocomplete="new-password" on input, but without any result. The suggestions is still here. :(

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue on a StackOverflow code snippet or any live editor like codesandbox.

Comment: I solved the problem. Instead of input type="text" I used a textarea styled like an input. So the browser stopped to push the suggestions :)